# ERROR: Your Tor Browser profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible

Tags: error, tor-install

I downloaded the last version of tor browser on Windows 7. I start the installation and everything seems to be ok, but when I try to start tor browser I get the error "Your Tor Browser profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible."

What can I try to do?

Thanks everybody in advance.

GL

Comment: Did you install it over the top of an existing installation? e.g. just extracted it into the same folder? if so, try a fresh directory, rather than the old one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer|! I tried it, and now I get a new error: "could not connect to tor control port"

Comment: That sounds like some kind of firewall/packetfilter, antivirus, or security software may be blocking connections. Tor Browser tries to connect to the control port of the Tor instance it launches on 127.0.0.1:9151 by default.

Comment: Mine gave that same first error message, i simply ran the 'start tor browser' shortcut as admin, it worked fine.

Comment: You shouldn't run Tor under root. There is no point of doing so.

Comment: So if you hide the Folder, unhide it.